# Set labels from array

Tags: symfony, twig, chart.js

I'm starting with chartjs and i'm already struggling. I want to set my labels with data I get from a query :

```
public function find4Chart($joueur){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

    $qb->join('p.partie','y')
        ->join('y.game','g')
        ->select('g.name')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(p) AS sumParties')
        ->where('p.joueur = :joueur')
        ->setParameter('joueur', $joueur)
        ->groupBY('g.name');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Then I set up the chart like this :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: [{{ chart.name }}],
```

But it gives me the following error and I don't know why or what to do here :/

> Key "name" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.

Thx !

Comment: Can you show us what the data structure the query returns looks like?

Comment: sure, it retourns me this : array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Bob27" ["sumParties"]=> string(1) "3" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Halve-it" ["sumParties"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your own answer - you could change this part:

```php
$arrChart = array();
foreach($chart as $c){
    $name = $c['name'];
    array_push($arrChart, $name);
}
```

into this:

```php
$arrChart = array_column($chart, 'name');
```

You can read more about `array_column` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it worked for me this way :

```
public function show(Joueur $joueur): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
    $chart = $em->getRepository(Played::class)->find4Chart($joueur);
    $arrChart = array();
    foreach($chart as $c){
        $name = $c['name'];
        array_push($arrChart, $name);
    }

    return $this->render('joueur/show.html.twig', [
        'joueur' => $joueur,
        'chart' => $arrChart,
    ]);
}
```

Chart :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: {{chart | json_encode | raw}},
```

I don't know if it's the right way to do it but it works, if any of you have a better idea, I'll take it ;)